# Installing x64 Access driver on x64 Windows 7 with 32 bit Office

Tags: java, windows, ms-access, jdbc

I'm developing a Java application which needs to write to an Access database.   I am working on a Windows 7 x64 machine, using an x64 JVM, but our network team has installed the x86 (32 bit) versions of Office applications on our machines.   So when I try to install the x64 Access driver on my machine, I get this message:

```
You cannot install the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 
because you currently have 32-bit Office products installed.   If you want to 
install 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010, you will first need to 
remove the 32 bit installation of Office products.   After uninstalling the 
following product(s), rerun setup in order to install 64-bit version of Microsoft 
Access Database Engine 2010:   

Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2007
```

Does anyone have a clever way of bypassing this message?

Comment: I had asked this question with a totally different title, which I edited at the last minute-  when I saved it with the new title, SO popped up with a question that had the information I needed.   See the duplicate for the answer.

Comment: depending on what your needs are, you can use [jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) and completely forgo the microsoft drivers.

Comment: I have managed to install both without side effects on Office installation and without using /passive option. Downside is that is tested and working only on one Office version for now.  [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver for x64 app - how to make it work with x86 MS Office installed?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30666663/378783