# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver for x64 app - how to make it work with x86 MS Office installed?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, connection-string, oledb

Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver is not working on my PC, I am trying to fix it.
Error on connection opening is: "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

Here is what i got now:

- I have built x64 C# ADO.NET console application with connection string for connecting to '*.mdb':

> "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..."

- I have two PC-s A and B, both have Windows 7 x64 and identical MS Office 2013 x86 version
- Same exacutable will run without problem on PC-A, and not on PC-B
- There are several other PCs with similar configurations, and all throw same exception using same executable

I have red so many questions with similar problems and all suggest using x64 Office version but this is not option for me. As I have PC-A which has x86 Office and x64 bit driver is working fine in x64 application I am looking for steps to discover why it works on that particular machine and how to replicate this on other machines.

Someone might mistake this question as duplicate of [hand-install-of-64-bit-ms-access-odbc-drivers-when-32-bit-office-is-present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116019/hand-install-of-64-bit-ms-access-odbc-drivers-when-32-bit-office-is-present) but it is not the case, i have tried to install x64 driver with /passive option but although then driver works from C# app I am unable to start Access at all on my PC after this. On PC-A you can work with Access with no problem and still use x64 driver.

Comment: Why downvote? Lost all day trying to figure this, no other Question had this solved to work with no problems and I found working example so I was sure that it can be done without /passive command which will most likely screw up your existing installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have replicated everything from working machine (PC-A) to my PC and i have entire Office x86 working together with x64 OLEDB Access drivers on same PC. Did this on 3 other PCs and all work with no problems for now.

Key is to install MS Office Professional Plus 2013 x86 first, then [AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). It seams that key is that Access Database Engine is for Office 2010, Office is 2013 and installation order is Office first. On one PC Office started some repair after Engine installation and finished it with no problems. Now also works OK.

O = Office, E = Access Database Engine.
Tried with O2013 and E2013 did't work, tried O2010 and E2013, and O2010 and same E2010, all failed. /passive option to install engine without complaining that x86 O is installed corrupted my O instalation and OS was unable to repair it. So of few tried combinations and orders only one worked, and this did not cause complaints from OS that other component is installed.